# How to send a date range of the month

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to send as a start date the first day of the month and as the end date the current day. I know hot to get the current day but i am not sure about the start date.

```
endDate = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
```

But how can i format the start date so that it returns the first day of the month?

```
startdate = ??
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Not day name, just like 05/01/2012 12:00 AM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new `DateTime` instance from the year and month of the current date:

```
// Get currect date in a variable, to avoid repeated calls (as DateTime.Now changes)
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

string startDate = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1).ToShortDateString();
string endDate = today.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just new up an instance of `DateTime` using the `endDate` values for year and month using 1 for the day:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

startdate = endDate.AddDays(endDate.Day * -1 + 1);